# Pull out Attributes from TSQL XML

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, dom

I have the following XML:

```
<help>
  <item field="field1" help="helptext" />
  <item field="field2" help="helptext" />
  <item field="field3" help="helptext" />
</help>
```

I have this stored in an XML DataType in SQL server and would like to pull out the fields and help text seperately. I.e a results set similar to:

```
 | field1 | helptext |  
 | field2 | helptext |  
 | field3 | helptext |
```

Does anybody know how to achieve this?

Kindest Regards,

Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @xml AS XML = '<help>
  <item field="field1" help="helptext" />
  <item field="field2" help="helptext" />
  <item field="field3" help="helptext" />
</help>'

select c.value('@field', 'varchar(max)') field, c.value('@help', 'varchar(max)') help
from @xml.nodes('/help/item') T(c);
```

To achieve the same when xml data is in a table field use:

```
SELECT c.value('@field', 'varchar(max)') field, c.value('@help', 'varchar(max)') help
FROM MyTable A CROSS APPLY A.MyXmlField.nodes('/help/item') T(c)
```

Where MyTable is the table with field MyXmlField containing xml data.

Comment: Thanks for the response here. This is worknig really well if the XML is a variable. I'm struggling linking this up to use it from a table though, as I'm creating a view for this.

Comment: Hello, This can be done with a CROSS Apply and is working now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

See if following helps:

```
DECLARE @processedXmlDoc int
DECLARE @inputDoc varchar(1000)

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @processedXmlDoc OUTPUT, @inputDoc 

SELECT    *
FROM       OPENXML (@processedXmlDoc , '/help/item',1)
            WITH (field varchar(20) 'field',
                  help varchar(20) 'helpText')

EXECUTE sp_xml_removedocument @idoc
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
DECLARE @input XML = '<help>
  <item field="field1" help="helptext" />
  <item field="field2" help="helptext" />
  <item field="field3" help="helptext" />
</help>'

SELECT
    Field = Item.value('@field', 'varchar(25)'),
    HELP = Item.value('@help', 'varchar(50)')
FROM
    @input.nodes('/help/item') AS XTbl(Item)
```